# The argument type 'Stream<List<dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<List<Brew>>?'

Tags: flutter

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamProvider<List>.value(
**value:DatabaseServices(uid: '').brews,** error on this

```
initialData: const [],
child
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `initialData` value like so:

```dart
initialData: const <Brew>[],
```